# Postgres constraint ensuring one column of many is present?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

What are good ways to add a constraint to PostgreSQL to check that exactly one column (from a set of columns) contains a non-null value?

*Update*: It is likely that I want to use a `check` expression as detailed in [Create Table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altertable.html) and [Alter Table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html).

*Update*: I'm looking through the available [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions.html).

*Update*: Just for background, here is the Rails validation logic I'm currently using:

```
validate :multi_column_validation
def multi_column_validation
  n = 0
  n += 1 if column_1
  n += 1 if column_2
  n += 1 if column_3
  unless 1 == n
    errors.add(:base, "Exactly one column from " +
      "column_1, column_2, column_3 must be present")
  end
end
```

To be clear, I'm looking for PSQL, not Ruby, here. I just wanted to show the logic I'm using since it is more compact than enumerating all "truth table" possibilities.

Comment: Are those columns booleans?

Comment: Clodoaldo: I'm interested in NULL or NOT NULL. (In my specific case, I have a mix of UUID and TEXT columns, but I don't think this is critical to the problem.)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL 9.6 you have the `num_nonnulls` and `num_nulls` [comparison functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE) that accept any number of VARIADIC arguments.

For example, this would make sure exactly one of the three columns is not null.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_only_one_is_not_null CHECK (num_nonnulls(col1, col2, col3) = 1);
```

### History & References

The [PostgreSQL 9.6.0 Release Notes from 2016-09-29](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.6.0/) say:

> Add variadic functions `num_nulls()` and `num_nonnulls()` that count the number of their arguments that are null or non-null (Marko Tiikkaja)

[On 2015-08-12, Marko Tiikkaja proposed this feature](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/55CB7FF1.70506%40joh.to) on the [pgsql-hacker mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/):

> I'd like to suggest $SUBJECT for inclusion in Postgres 9.6.  I'm sure everyone would've found it useful at some point in their lives, and the fact that it can't be properly implemented in any language other than C  I think speaks for the fact that we as a project should provide it.
>
> A quick and dirty proof of concept (patch attached):
>
> ```
> =# select count_nulls(null::int, null::text, 17, 'bar');
>   count_nulls
> -------------
>             2
> (1 row)
> ```
>
> Its natural habitat would be CHECK constraints, e.g:
>
> ```
>   CHECK (count_nulls(a,b,c) IN (0, 3))
> ```

Avid code historians can follow more discussion from that point. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Very useful. Even the man doc relegates it to a couple lines at the far end..

Comment: @Davos I agree! I just marked this as the correct answer.

Comment: @gerardnl I hope you don't mind the history and references section. If nothing else, I think it will help more people see how the PostgreSQL community works.

Comment: Brilliant, this is makes it easy to maintain when adding new columns over time.

Answer (score 52):

**2021-09-17 update**: As of today, [gerardnll provides a better answer (the best IMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223096/109618):

> "Since PostgreSQL 9.6 you have the num_nonnulls and num_nulls comparison functions that accept any number of VARIADIC arguments."

In order to help people find the cleanest solution, I recommend you upvote [gerardnll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223096/109618).

(FYI, I'm the same person who asked the original question.)

---

#### Here is my original answer from 2013

Here is an elegant two column solution according to the ["constraint -- one or the other column not null" PostgreSQL message board](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060906142112.GA2657@yagni.com):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (
  (column_1 IS NULL) != (column_2 IS NULL));
```

(But the above approach is not generalizable to three or more columns.)

If you have three or more columns, you can use the truth table approach illustrated by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15178981/109618). However, I consider the following to be easier to maintain because you don't have to type out the logical combinations:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (
  (CASE WHEN column_1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
  (CASE WHEN column_2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
  (CASE WHEN column_3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1;
```

To compact this, it would be useful to create a custom function so that the `CASE WHEN column_k IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` boilerplate could be removed, leaving something like:

```
(non_null_count(column_1) +
non_null_count(column_2) +
non_null_count(column_3)) = 1
```

That may be as compact as PSQL will allow (?). That said, I'd prefer to get to this kind of syntax if possible:

```
non_null_count(column_1, column_2, column_3) = 1
```

Comment: There is a `boolean` to `integer` cast defined (see `\dC boolean` in `psql`) and the C-style results are the only sensible things for it to do given the [possible boolean literals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) so you can `(null is null)::int` to get a `1` or `(null is not null)::int` to get a `0`.

Comment: MatheusOl picked up where I left off and suggested a [more elegant solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15180124/109618).

Comment: That first constraint really is elegant.

Comment: I prefer this answer to the "more elegant solution".  Both solutions (2 column and 3+ column) are very straightforward and require no function definitions.  Nice and crisp. Not as DRY, perhaps, but very nice and understandable.

Comment: I like both solutions too. Even with three columns the first option is still straight forward ... CHECK ( (c1 is not null and c2 is null and c3 is null) or (c2 is not null and c1 is null and c3 is null) or (c3 is not null and c1 is null and c2 is null) )

Comment: There is a missing closing parenthesis in the second solution. Add it in the end before the `;`

Comment: @DavidJ. The original answer marked correct shows a custom PL/pgSQL function. This answer is useful both because the SQL is explicit and because some users don't have access to create stored functions. Since there is now a built-in function `num_nonnulls` to accomplish the same, and your closing statement is that you'd prefer as such, then that answer should now be marked correct >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223096/1335793

Comment: As of 2021, the best answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223096/109618: "Since PostgreSQL 9.6 you have the `num_nonnulls` and `num_nulls` comparison functions that accept any number of VARIADIC arguments." (I'm the author of this answer from 2013, so I'm going to edit it to point to the better answer.)

Answer (score 20):

I think the most clean and generic solution is to create a function to count the null values from some arguments. For that you can use the [pseudo-type `anyarray`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) and a SQL function like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_not_nulls(p_array anyarray)
RETURNS BIGINT AS
$$
    SELECT count(x) FROM unnest($1) AS x
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

With that function, you can create your `CHECK CONSTRAINT` as:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD chk_only_one_is_not_null CHECK(count_not_nulls(array[col1, col2, col3]) = 1);
```

This will only work if the columns are of the same data type. If it's not the case, you can cast them, as text for instance (as you just care for the null case):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD chk_only_one_is_not_null CHECK(count_not_nulls(array[col1::text, col2::text, col3::text]) = 1);
```

As well remembered by @muistooshort, you can create the function with [variadic arguments](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS), which makes it clear to call:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_not_nulls(variadic p_array anyarray)
RETURNS BIGINT AS
$$
    SELECT count(x) FROM unnest($1) AS x
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD chk_only_one_is_not_null CHECK(count_not_nulls(col1, col2, col3) = 1);
```

Comment: Can you cast inside the function instead, making it generic for all (or most) column types?

Comment: @DavidJames, not AFAIK. But you will only need to cast if the data-types of the columns are different, if they are the same (independent of which) there is no need to cast.

Comment: You can write [variadic functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) in PL/pgSQL if you don't like the "artificial arrayification" of the arguments when calling `count_not_nulls`.

Comment: @muistooshort, great idea (I always forget this great feature). You can use SQL for that. I updated the question to make it easy for others to try.

Comment: Cool. This answer is growing on me, but I'm still not a fan of having to typecast if I have different column types.

Comment: In more recent versions of postgres you should add a constraint:
`ALTER TABLE your_table
      ADD CONSTRAINT chk_only_one_is_not_null CHECK(count_not_nulls(array[col1, col2, col3]) = 1);`

Answer (score 18):

As hinted by [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short):

```
alter table t
add constraint only_one_null check (
    (col1 is not null)::integer + (col2 is not null)::integer = 1
)
```

Comment: I want exactly one **non**-null value, so: `(col1 IS NOT NULL)::int + (col2 IS NOT NULL)::int = 1`

Answer (score 4):

A bit clumsy, but should do the trick:

```
create table foo
(
   col1 integer,
   col2 integer,
   col3 integer,
   constraint one_is_not_null check 
        (    (col1 is not null and col2 is null and col3 is null) 
          or (col1 is null and col2 is not null and col3 is null)
          or (col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is not null)
        )
)
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to compact this and/or generalize it to `k` columns?

Comment: @DavidJames: I don't think there is an easy solution to that

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using the [built-in array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD chk_only_one_is_not_null CHECK (array_length(array_remove(ARRAY[col1, col2, col3], NULL), 1) = 1);
```

Comment: I like this answer, it is interesting for the sake of variety, but overly complex for what it does. Better to use something more explicit like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223096/1335793