# SQLAlchemy: Any constraint to check one of the two columns is not null?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This may be totally stupid thing to ask but I have such a requirement in my model where atleast either `category` or `parent_category` is `not null`

My model looks like

```
class BudgetCategories(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'budget_categories'
    uuid = Column('uuid', GUID(), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,
                  unique=True)
    budget_id = Column(GUID(), ForeignKey('budgets.uuid'), nullable=False)
    budget = relationship('Budget', backref='budgetCategories')
    category = Column('category', sa.types.String, nullable=True)
    parent_category = Column('parent_category', sa.types.String, nullable=True)
    amount = Column('amount', Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)
    recurring = Column('recurring', sa.types.Boolean,
                       nullable=False)
    created_on = Column('created_on', sa.types.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        nullable=False)
```

How can I specify that. I don't even know what to try

Any pointers appreciated

I am using `PostgreSQL` as the backend database

Comment: At least one of `category` and `parent_category` is `not null` or exactly one of them is `not null`?

Comment: Atleast. if both are populated -> good, but atleast either category or parent_category is not null. I hope that clarifies

Comment: a `category is not null or parent_category is not null` CHECK constraint would do it at the database level, not sure about the Python level though.

Answer (score 20):

I am not 100% sure about the `PostgreSQL` syntax, but following addition to your `BudgetCategories` model should do the trick using [`CheckConstraint`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.CheckConstraint):

```
class BudgetCategories(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'budget_categories'
    # ...

    # @note: new
    __table_args__ = (
            CheckConstraint('NOT(category IS NULL AND parent_category IS NULL)'),
            )
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. What about in cases where you have more than 2 fields and only one of them should have a value, while the rest should be null? Thanks

Comment: @ChickenFeet: consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15180124/99594) or [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5279/25414) answers

Answer (score 8):

I needed **XOR** behavior in my SQLalchemy models. I come up with the following definition (backend used: PostgreSQL):

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    CheckConstraint
)

class ScheduledNotebook(Base):
    __table_args__ = (
        (CheckConstraint('(uuid::text IS NULL) <> (notebook_path IS NULL)', name='uuid_xor_notebook_path')),
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    notebook_path = Column(String, nullable=True, unique=True)
    uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=True)
```

and following alembic migration (note: autogenerate won't detect it - you have to add it manually):

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_check_constraint(
        'uuid_xor_notebook_path',
        table_name='scheduled_notebooks',
        schema='metadata',
        condition='(uuid::text IS NULL) <> (notebook_path IS NULL)'
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_constraint('uuid_xor_notebook_path')
```

and it works like a charm:

**- only notebook_path - OK**

```
datalake=#  INSERT INTO scheduled_notebooks (schedule,enabled,owner, notebook_path) VALUES ('{"kind":"hourly"}',true,'akos', '/a/b/c/d/e.ipynb');
INSERT 0 1
```

**- only uuid - OK**

```
datalake=#  INSERT INTO scheduled_notebooks (schedule,enabled,owner, uuid) VALUES ('{"kind":"hourly"}',true,'akos', '7792bd5f-5819-45bf-8902-8cf43102434d');
INSERT 0 1
```

**- both uuid and notebook_path - FAILS as desired**

```
datalake=#  INSERT INTO scheduled_notebooks (schedule,enabled,owner, uuid, notebook_path) VALUES ('{"kind":"hourly"}',true,'akos', '7792bd5f-5819-45bf-8902-8cf43102434f', '/a/b/c/d');
ERROR:  new row for relation "scheduled_notebooks" violates check constraint "uuid_xor_notebook_path"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (567, /a/b/c/d, {"kind": "hourly"}, t, akos, null, null, null, 7792bd5f-5819-45bf-8902-8cf43102434f).
```

**- neither uuid nor notebook_path - FAILS as desired**

```
datalake=#  INSERT INTO scheduled_notebooks (schedule,enabled,owner) VALUES ('{"kind":"hourly"}',true,'akos');
ERROR:  new row for relation "scheduled_notebooks" violates check constraint "uuid_xor_notebook_path"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (568, null, {"kind": "hourly"}, t, akos, null, null, null, null).
```

Comment: Thanks, works for flask-sqlalchemy as well.

Answer (score 3):

I hope is not too late but this should do the trick and it is checked to work with a PostGreSQL DB:

```
class BudgetCategories(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'budget_categories'
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('coalesce(category , parent_category ) is not null'),
    )
    # ...
```

Comment: Can anyone please explain why it's down voted? Is it because of some performance implications I am not aware of? Maybe DB back-end support? I am really curious, because I personally find this solution nifty.

Comment: I'd be interested to know @radzak. Maybe because it's less obvious to read? Very debatable. I can't say it's faulty.

Comment: A bit more of explanation would be nice. For those wondering, `COALESCE` is a Postgres function that will return the first `NOT NULL` element of the arguments or `NULL` if all arguments are `NULL`. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/

Comment: @radzak I dont think this handles the case of them both being filled

Answer (score 2):

When using the PostgreSQL backend, you can also use the [num_nonnulls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE) function for this purpose:

```
class BudgetCategories(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'budget_categories'
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('num_nonnulls(category, parent_category) = 1'),
    )
```

Comment: I like it, but it would fail if both of the columns are `NOT NULL`.
You could change it to `num_nonnulls() > 0` or `num_nulls() = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem some weeks ago, too and was provided with the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73797844/postgresql-value-is-only-allowed-in-one-of-two-columns/73797957#73797957). So translated to sqlalchemy I'd guess (not yet tested!!):

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CheckConstraint

class MyClass(Base):
    __table_args__ = (
        (CheckConstraint(
            'num_nulls(nullif(trim(col_a::text), ''), nullif(trim(col_b::text), '')) = 1', 
            name='uuid_xor_notebook_path')),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col_a = Column(String, nullable=True, unique=True)
    col_b = Column(String, nullable=True, unique=True)
```

However for aesthetic reasons I prefer @andilabs solution. To still take into account empty fields for this reason, one could leverage another [solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291723/sqlalchemy-can-i-map-an-empty-string-to-null-in-the-ddl-i-want-a-nullable-inte) and write:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CheckConstraint

class MyClass(Base):
    __table_args__ = (
        (CheckConstraint(
            '(col_a::text IS NULL) <> (col_b IS NULL)', 
            name='uuid_xor_notebook_path')),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col_a = Column(String, nullable=True, unique=True)
    col_b = Column(String, nullable=True, unique=True)

    @validates('col_a', 'col_b')
    def empty_string_to_null(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, str) and value == '':
            return None
        else:
            return value
```

Not really the shortest of all snippets, I admit...

Comment: whoops, I copy-pasted code snippets from above to save me some typing. That's why the constraint-name is somewhat stupid in my example. but you get the idea...