# How to check if at least one of two specific fields in a table is NOT NULL in Sqlalchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, check-constraints

I have two fields:

```
class Person(base):
     field1 = Column(String(32), unique=True, nullable=True)
     field2 = Column(String(128), unique=True, nullable=True)
     field3 = ...
     ...
```

I need to create a constraint, to check if at least one of `[field1, field2]` is available.  I guess I need to use `CheckConstraint`, but I failed to get a result.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947382/895659) post:

```
__table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('NOT(field1 IS NULL AND field2 IS NULL)'),
        )
```